# Is there a Android Port for the 7zip library?

Tags: android, compression, 7zip

I am thinking of porting it, if there isn't one already available. Google search yielded one result, but that port was incomplete and did not compile either... If there is an already existing android port of this library, then i do not want to expend un-necessary effort on it.

Comment: there is a java sdk that may be compatible with android.

Comment: maybe helpfull links http://code.google.com/p/andro7z/
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=856415

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I don't know exactly what '7zip library' means, and what is your Android device architecture.

Assuming '7zip library' is what compiles when building p7zip command-line utilities, and your Android device can run 64-bit Intel executables, I got good news for you.

I have successfully built and tested 7z executable and libraries it depends on for Android-on-64-bit-Intel. The recipe is [part of my repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krisk0/halfbreed-software/master/p7zip/recipe.txt).

Disclaimer: I am the one who published ebuild scripts that build [bionic](https://github.com/krisk0/pc-linux-android), [musl and uclibc](https://github.com/krisk0/alien-libc) toolchains on [github](https://github.com/).